# Multiple markers at this line android

Tags: android

`EditText et;`

Causes an error of: `Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token`
But I could'nt find the syntax error. Please help

```
private static final String Button = null;
    public Integer user_id;
    public String client_list_id;
    JSONArray listarray = null;
    ListView listview;
    ListView lv;
    Button bt;
    EditText et;
    lv = (ListView).findViewById(R.id.listview);
    bt= (Button).findViewById(R.id.manualbtn);
    et = (EditText).findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    View v = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> firstList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        user_id = getArguments().getInt("user_id");

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } 
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

move `lv = (ListView).findViewById(R.id.listview);
    bt= (Button).findViewById(R.id.manualbtn);
    et = (EditText).findViewById(R.id.editText1);` into your onCreate() method.
and use setContentView() method with appropriate layout in your activity's onCreate() method in which your edittext and other views are or generate a view dynamically which hold your these elements

Comment: Ya right but in this code there is no setContentView();